# Return only the modified records in a table, using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, lag

I'm attempting to return only the modified records in a table, using T-SQL.

This is what I've done thus far:

```
 BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Test

    CREATE TABLE #Test
        (SetName nvarchar(100),
        [Timestamp] datetime,
        Value smallint)

    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Alpha', GETDATE(), 1)
    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Alpha', GETDATE(), 0)
    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Alpha', GETDATE(), 1)
    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Beta', GETDATE(), 1)
    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Beta', GETDATE(), 1)
    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Beta', GETDATE(), 1)
    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Gamma', GETDATE(), 1)
    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Gamma', GETDATE(), 0)
    INSERT INTO #Test VALUES('Gamma', GETDATE(), 1)

    SELECT * FROM #Test

END;
```

Results:

```
SetName Timestamp               Value

Alpha   2022-05-23 12:58:41.100 1
Alpha   2022-05-23 12:58:41.101 0
Alpha   2022-05-23 12:58:41.102 1
Beta    2022-05-23 12:58:41.103 1
Beta    2022-05-23 12:58:41.104 1
Beta    2022-05-23 12:58:41.105 1
Gamma   2022-05-23 12:58:41.106 1
Gamma   2022-05-23 12:58:41.107 0
Gamma   2022-05-23 12:58:41.108 1
```

Expected results:

```
Alpha   2022-05-23 12:58:41.101 0 -- Changed from 1 to 0
Alpha   2022-05-23 12:58:41.102 1 -- Changed from 0 to 1
Gamma   2022-05-23 12:58:41.107 0 -- Changed from 1 to 0
Gamma   2022-05-23 12:58:41.108 1 -- Changed from 0 to 1
```

The following statement returns all the 0 to 1, and 1 to 0 records and I don't understand why:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 
    SetName, [Timestamp], Value, lag(Value, 1, -1) OVER (ORDER BY [Timestamp]) AS LastValue
FROM #Test
) 

SELECT 
    SetName, [Timestamp], [Value]
FROM
    cte
WHERE value <> LastValue
```

Comment: You want yo track the changes on the whole data set or against each SetName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track the changes at whole dataset, you were almost there, you just need to remove the first row by using `LastValue <> -1`.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
    SetName, [Timestamp], Value, lag(Value, 1, -1) OVER (ORDER BY [Timestamp]) AS LastValue
FROM #Test
) 

SELECT 
    SetName, [Timestamp], [Value]
FROM
    CTE
WHERE value<>Lastvalue
AND Lastvalue<> -1; --Add this filter to remove the rows which doesn't have any Lag Value
```

To track the changes at `SetName` level.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
   SetName, [Timestamp], Value, Lag(Value, 1, -1) OVER (PARTITION BY SetName ORDER BY [Timestamp]) AS LastValue
FROM #Test
) 

SELECT 
    SetName, [Timestamp], [Value]
FROM
    CTE
WHERE Value<>LastValue
AND LastValue <> -1;
```

db<>fiddle: [Try here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf5bb9b74edadca5bf22712a774e19b4)

**Note:** From the given dataset, modified records at SetName level and at whole dataset is same.

**Assumption:** Each Timestamp value is  different.

Answer (score 2):

This solution *assumes* that 2 rows for a single `SetName` *cannot* have the same value for `Timestamp` (2 rows for different values of `SetName` is fine).

One method is to use gaps and islands to put the values into groups, and then omit group 0 from the data:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SetName,
           [Timestamp], --timestamp is a deprecrated synonym for rowversion; I don't recommend it's use as a column name
           [value],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SetName ORDER BY Timestamp) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SetName, [Value] ORDER BY Timestamp) AS Grp
    FROM #Test)
SELECT SetName,
       [Timestamp], --timestamp is a deprecrated synonym for rowversion; I don't recommend it's use as a column name
       [value]
FROM CTE
WHERE Grp != 0
ORDER BY [Timestamp];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c44742516e5d35a4e6aba9d2b932ce2)

If 2 rows *can* have the same value, then *hopefully* you have an always ascending value you can [use in the `ORDER BY`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c103c6c6c9aab9b578566f6d73665848) as well; otherwise you have no way of knowing what the "first" row is.

Comment: Can you check this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dff17ebde9b49ac639b03a37dcbe2637), I have changed the value of first row 'Beta' from 1 to 0.

Comment: What is it you want me to check, @Abinash ..?

Comment: I am suspecting the query is giving wrong output, Ideally it should give 1 row for 'Beta' after the change. Let me know if otherwise.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, @Abinash . Only the OP can answer that.